# How to fix 'validation failed error' during a sign up in MongoDb / NodeJs Express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, forms, mongoose

I am trying to save a user to mongodb database using post request as follow, but I got the error : 
"Error: User validation failed: mail: Path `mail` is required., pseudo: Path `pseudo` is required., password: Path `password` is required."

PS : I edited in response to Eol but my question / and the bug are still present.

Details error :

```
 errors: {
    mail: ValidatorError: Path `mail` is required.
       [...] {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'mail',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
```

my controller :

```
exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {
      const user = new User({
        mail: req.body.mail,
        password: req.body.password,
        pseudo: req.body.pseudo,
      });
      user
        .save()
        .then(() => res.statuts(201).json({ message: "User created !" }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err) )
    }
```

My User Model :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator"); 

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  pseudo: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  mail: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator); 

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

My front :

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const pseudo = e.target[0].value, 
    password = e.target[1].value, 
    mail = e.target[2].value 
    const data = new FormData()
    data.set("pseudo", pseudo)
    data.set("password", password)
    data.set("mail", mail)

    axios.post(url, data)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(res => console.log(res))
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div >
            <label htmlFor="pseudo">Pseudo</label>
            <input name="pseudo" type="text" id="pseudo"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="true"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="mail">email</label>
            <input name="mail" type="email" id="mail"/>
          </div>
          <input
            type="submit"
            to="/user"
            value="Sign up"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you pass to mongoose does not contain a field called `mail` instead you pass it as `email`. So you need to map the `email` field from your request payload to `mail`:

```
const user = new User({
        mail: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        pseudo: req.body.pseudo,
 });
```

The other thing you need to fix is your client side. You're sending form-data instead of a json-body. Change it to:

```
const data = {  pseudo: e.target[0].value, 
                password: e.target[1].value, 
                mail: e.target[2].value };

axios.post(url, data) // rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it but the bug is still there, same error message

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body)` say?

Comment: Indeed console.log(req.body) return `body: {}`

Comment: Edited the answer, you need to fix the client side as well. Note that you need to enable express' bodyparser: `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Thank you everything works well, I was baited because my http request contains expected data in the network tab of my console

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're getting values out of `req.body`. It seems to me that might be it. Try to log the values of `req.body` in your signup controller. Newer versions of Expressjs don't use the bodyParser middleware anymore, instead you'd use `app.use(express.urlencoded())` and `app.use(express.json())`. Can't comment on your post yet, so that's why this answer might be kinda a suggestion.